# i can not seem to get it exactly, i am getting the factorials but cant seem to find a way to put in the combination formula

Tags: python, python-2.7, function, methods

i have written the code but am not able to get the formula of combination to go in, i am very new to this and use these extra excercises to help with math, can you help what to improve or how to complete?

```
n=(10)
fact=3
while(n>0):
    fact=fact*n
    n=n-1
print("Factorial of the number is: ")
print(fact)


n=int(6)
fact=1
while(n>0):
    fact=fact*n
    n=n-1
print("Factorial of the number is: ")
print(fact)
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGEDb.png

Comment: Your code seems to work, except for the fact that it's not indented properly.  I'm assuming that's cut-and-paste, not a problem with your original code.  (I fixed it in your question).  I'm not sure what you're asking--do you just want advice on improving it?

Comment: did you check the picture?, i found a way to get the factorial, but it is not really the way it is asked, but thank you !

Comment: If you're talking about the formula, that's for figuring out how to choose k items out of a total of n items (e.g., making a pizza with 4 toppings out of a total of 9 choices).  I'm not sure whether you're asking about the math or the Python.  You've found a way to find the factorial correctly, although you'd be better off defining it as a function that takes in a parameter (maybe you haven't gotten that far yet, in which case your code is fine for now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def fact_(n):
    fact = 1
    while (n > 0):
        fact = fact * n
        n = n - 1
    return fact

#mario
result_m = fact_(10)/(fact_(3)*fact_(7))
print(int(result_m))

#luigi
result_l = fact_(9)/(fact_(4)*fact_(5))
print(int(result_l))
```

output:

```
120
126
```

NOTE: in your formula for mario : n = 10 k = 3, for luigi: n = 9 k = 4

Answer (score -1):

Taken from https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/factorial-in-python/

```
    n = 23
    fact = 1

    for i in range(1,n+1): 
        fact = fact * i 

    print ("The factorial of 23 is : ",end="") 
    print (fact)
```

Or use the maths module:

```
import math 
print (math.factorial(23))
```

Comment: thank you,but if i am not mistaken,this is for python 3x nd up, i am using 2.7